# Eclipse CDT: doesn't show name a macro appears in

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

When searching for macro references, Eclipse displays file+line the macro is referenced it. I would like to file+line+**function**.

Searching for a other type of data (e.g. function) will display file+line+**function** as expected, so maybe something should be tweaked in Eclipse configuration for macros?

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. On my Eclipse it shows me the macro with defines translated.

Comment: @LP Don't sure you comment is relevant for my question :)

Comment: @dimba Can you add a cropped screenshot of what the tooltip looks like?

Comment: @dimba Another CDT committer has taken the time to add the necessary parsing information and now the next release of CDT will have this support https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508216

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update - Jan 2017

The next release of CDT (CDT 9.3, part of Eclipse Oxygen to be released in June 2017) will have support for showing function containing the macro reference. See [Bug 508216](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508216) for more details.

The rest of this answer is the original answer.

### TL;DR

There is no way in Eclipse CDT to display the function a macro is referenced in because such information is not included in the index when the index is built.

### Pictures

To ensure that we are talking about the same thing I provide some visuals.

Given a simplified C file containing functions, macros and globals:

**Example Code**

```
#define MACRO(X) ((X) + 2)
int function(int);
int global;

int function_results_are_in(void) {
    int i = 0;
    i = MACRO(i);
    i = function(i);
    i += global;
    return i;
}
```

Doing a search using one of the following methods that uses the C/C++ Index (as opposed to a file/grep style search):

**Setup**

- *References in Workspace* of selection using one of:

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
  - Right-click -> *References* -> *Workspace*
- *Search* menu -> *C/C++ Search* and search for references, like this picture:
  [image]

**Results - Function search**

As you can see with searches for functions, the result shows the containing function name:

[image: function search]

**Results - Macro search**

But for the macro search, there is no containing function name:

[image: macro search]

### Under the hood

Each search result in the *C/C++ Search* results is  [`LineSearchElement.Match`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/search/LineSearchElement.java#n35). If its [`fEnclosingElement`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/search/LineSearchElement.java#n39) is `null` then there is no function to display.

Taking one step back you can see that the [match is created](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/search/CSearchQuery.java#n259) from a matching [`IIndexName`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/parser/org/eclipse/cdt/core/index/IIndexName.java). The `Match.fEnclosingElement` field is filled from the result of `IIndexName.getEnclosingDefinition()`.

In the case of a macro reference the concrete type of `IIndexName` is a [`PDOMMacroReferenceName`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/parser/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/PDOMMacroReferenceName.java), and [the implementation](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/parser/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/PDOMMacroReferenceName.java#n298) of `getEnclosingDefinition` is simply `return null`.